# Add custom button in radWizard

Tags: .net, visual-studio, button, telerik, wizard

I am working with a rad Wizard with 3 steps and with the Cancel, Previous and Next buttton. The thing is i want that in the 2 step of the wizard  to add another button for example "Generate" and to remove Next Button.

I googled and find some examples with localization but it doesnt work for me since i want to have that Next Button in my other steps.

Another example i found online is this one:

```
RadButtonElement radButtonElement1 = new RadButtonElement();
radButtonElement1.Text = "Generate";
radButtonElement1.MinSize = new Size(100, 24);
radButtonElement1.Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
radButtonElement1.Margin = new Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);

this.radWizard1.CommandArea.CommandElements.Add(radButtonElement1);
```

and i putted this inside

```
public void WizardCommandArea(RadWizardElement wizardElement)
        { }
```

I also created

```
public WizardCommandArea CommandArea { get; set; }
```

but for some reason the line

```
this.radWizard1.CommandArea.CommandElements.Add(radButtonElement1);
```

is givin me errors, starting from CommandArea saying

"'Telerik.Web.UI.RadWizard' does not contain a definition for 'CommandArea' and no extension method 'CommandArea' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadWizard' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    "

Any idea where am i doing wrong? what am i missin?